# How can I select a column from the first record?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created following model

```
module UserInfo
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = 'vUserDetails'

    default_scope { order(date_entered: :desc) }

  end
end
```

How can I produce the following query using this model?

```
SELECT TOP 1 Column1 
FROM vUserDetails
WHERE vUserDetails.UserID = @user_id
ORDER BY DateEntered DESC
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use ActiveRecord to access an existing schema that doesn't conform to Rails naming conventions. Unless you *have* to maintain this schema, you're much better off rewriting it the way Rails expects it.

Answer (score 0):

`UserInfo.first` will give you the first record, ordered by the `order` defined in your `default_scope`.

If you really want to select only the column `Column1`, then you would use `UserInfo.select(:Column1).first`.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get latest record. am i doing UserInfo.select(:column1).first in model?

Comment: @User7354632781 That question makes no sense. You do it where you need it. In a controller, typically, but it could be anywhere.